# IE <= 8 equivalent to selection.getRangeAt()?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I need to get the range object of the current selection. The following works in most browsers:

```
 range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
```

Is there an equivalent native JavaScript command for IE7/8 ?

Comment: When you have selected text, this retrieves the range object of your selection.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. IE <= 8 has selection and range functionality but it's very different to other browsers. The nearest equivalent is:

```
var range = document.selection.createRange();
```

... which will (usually) create you a proprietary [`TextRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object representing the selected content.

At the risk of promoting my own stuff, you may be interested in my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library, which provides a DOM Range and Selection API in all major browsers, in particular IE <= 8.