# What is equivalent to the getRangeAt() method in IE < 9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, range

I need the equivalent to the getRangeAt() method in Internet Explorer before version 9

```
if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    // What shall I write here to do the same thing in IE before version 9
}


var table = document.createElement("table");
table.border = 1;
table.className = "tabley";
range.insertNode(table);
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9083705/778118

Comment: ... or this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5421892/778118

Answer (score 0):

document.selection.createRange(); is the code which creates a range object in IE<9 and is equivalent to getRangeAt method used in IE>= 9

Comment: That usually creates a `TextRange`, which serves a similar purpose to a DOM Range but has a very different API, so they're not really equivalent.